# how to choose point spacing to approximate a parametric curve using line segments?

Tags: numerical-methods, graphing-functions

Suppose I have a parametric equation for a curve $\vec{r} = f(t)$, which I wish to draw using line segments between some set of points at times $t_0, t_1, t_2,$ etc.

If I want to achieve a given maximum error between the line segments and the curve, how do I choose the spacing between time points? I know it must be related to the local curvature, which I can calculate, but I'm not really sure how. (And I'd look it up, but I'm not sure what search terms to use.)

I'm interested in the general question, and also the specific question for conic sections $r = \frac{A}{1 - e \cos \theta}$ where $\theta = kt$.

Comment: There's a lot written on approximating a polygonal curve by another one (see, for example, http://cs.joensuu.fi/~koles/dissertation/Thesis_Kolesnikov_Ch3.pdf ) but this problem (say, for smooth curves) sounds simpler and I'm surprised I can't find what you're looking for.